# Android (Xamarin): BottomNavigationView not appearing in the right place

Tags: c#, android, .net, xml, xamarin

I am trying to implement a bottom navigation bar for my Android application (API 30), using the `BottomNavigationView` class from the `Android.Support.Design.Widget` namespace (Xamarin.Android.Support.Design library, version 28.0.0.3).
I am following the explanation from here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/exploring-androids-bottom-navigation-view/

This is what the layout file looks like:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schema.android.com/apk/res/res-auto"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_above="@+id/navigator"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView android:id="@+id/navigator"
                                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                        android:layout_height="64dp"
                                                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                                                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                                                        app:elevation="16dp"
                                                        app:menu="@menu/navigator"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the menu file:

```xml
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/home"
          android:icon="@drawable/home"
          android:title="Home"
          android:enabled="true"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/library"
          android:icon="@drawable/library"
          android:title="Library"
          android:enabled="true"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
          android:icon="@drawable/search"
          android:title="Search"
          android:enabled="true"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

The problem is that while it's visible, it appears at the top of the screen rather than at the bottom, which is the exact opposite of what a bottom navigation bar is supposed to do.
Furthermore, it doesn't show the icons. It just appears as a blank white bar at the top of the page.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: check this sample to see if it works https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin-Templates/tree/master/Xamarin.Android-Templates/Projects/BottomTabsApp

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT that sample doesn't even compile in API 30, unfortunately. Even if it did, it seems to have elements that I don't need in my application at the moment.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to compile (albeit with quite a few errors). And yes, the `BottomNavigationView` works on that one. I'll try modifying my code to be similar to it and respond again if I still can't get it to work.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT it works now. I changed my layout file to match the one from that example and made a few tweaks. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).